# can not run sudo in a rails resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell, resque, sudo

I have a resque worker which will run some shell command.

for example

`` ruby
`sudo echo "XXX" >> xx.log` ``

but when worker run, will raise below error

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

I have add 'whoami' debug code to find which user run this sudo command,
and also set this user's group "test" when execute command will don't need password.
I'm also run same command in shell console, it works right, don't need input password.

sudo visudo

`%test ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL`

but when the worker run sudo, will says above error, require input password.

Who can tell me why?
Thanks.

Comment: why do you need sudo?

Answer (score 0):

I am really hesitant to offer this as a "fix" because @AJcodez asks correctly, *"why do you need sudo?"* However, you can probably get around the tty requirement by adding the following:

```
Defaults requiretty
Defaults: %test !requiretty
```

to the `/etc/sudoers` file, but please use the `visudo` command. Also, is `test` here a user or a group? I also suspect that your sudoers line is malformed. The syntax is:

```
jane ALL=(LIST_OF_COMMANDS) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Where you seem to have it set to run the NOPASSWD setting for all zero commands the `%test` group can run. Or I could be misunderstanding your paste here.